# Draw scratch block shape in android using java

Tags: java, android, canvas, view, mit-scratch

I want to draw the first block type that in the picture at the bottom  in android java using Canvas how can i draw it i tried many ways to draw it but every time its shape is not like the one in the picture [image: scratch block]

Comment: You already have the PNG, so what's there to draw other than `drawBitmap`? If you have additional requirements (e.g. scalable), please say so. If you want advice on improving your code, please post your best effort.